# Processing an array of overridden methods depends if it is arbitrary or in alternance

Tags: java, algorithm, lambda, overriding, time-complexity

I have this piece of code and I want to know the cause of the difference between the time of execution of the first input and the second.
I think it should take the same time because I am calling the same method which do nothing in 2 objects.
but input1 (which is an alternation of 2 instances) takes on my computer 5 seconds.
and input2 (which is an arbitrary choosing between 2 instances) takes on my computer 17 seconds.

```
public class Program {


    private static final Runnable FIRST_INSTANCE = () -> {};
    private static final Runnable SECOND_INSTANCE = () -> {};

    private static Runnable[] input1() {
        Runnable[] array = new Runnable[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = i % 2 == 0 ? FIRST_INSTANCE : SECOND_INSTANCE;
        }
        return array;
    }


    private static Runnable[] input2() {
        Random rnd = new Random(0);
        Runnable[] array = new Runnable[10000];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = rnd.nextBoolean() ? FIRST_INSTANCE : SECOND_INSTANCE;
        }
        return array;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable[] input1 = input1();
        Runnable[] input2 = input2();

        solve(input1);
        solve(input2);

    }

    private static void solve(Runnable[] array) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        for (int j = 0; j < 500000; j++) {
            for (Runnable r : array) {
                r.run();
            }
        }
        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000000.0);
    }
}
```

I think it is not related to cache because they use the same instances, and it is not a problem of which is called first because I try to call input2 before input1 and I get the same results (input2 is always slower).

Comment: I start to calculate time after creating the arrays. rnd.nextBoolean() and i % 2 times is not calculated here.

Comment: I wrote already in the question.  I try to call input2 before input1 and I get the same results (input2 is always slower). @ErwinBolwidt

Comment: Hmm, strange even if doing array2 first, the results are just as bad.

Comment: It could be related to branch prediction - perhaps a predictable alternating pattern is caught by the CPU but not a random pattern. But I'm just guessing. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-processing-a-sorted-array-faster-than-processing-an-unsorted-array

Comment: Scary Wombat, that's not even the strange part. The strange part is the update to my answer I'm about to write :)

Comment: Do you think it is related to branch prediction?

Answer (score 2):

Some kind of compiler optimization is at play.

I've tried your code with 50000 iterations instead of 500000, because life is short. My times are roughly 10 times better than yours.

First, I've ran your code

```
0.502928476
1.68480928
```

Then I tried to run the same with `-Djava.compiler=NONE` (disables JIT):

```
25.267888581
24.742234792
```

Note how awful the timing became. JIT is definitely a suspect here.

Then I tried to make `input1` less uniform:

`array[i] = i % 21 == 0 ? FIRST_INSTANCE : SECOND_INSTANCE;`

and that hasn't made a difference. Then I tried to remove the pattern from `input1`:

`array[i] = (int)(Math.sqrt(i) * Math.sqrt(i)) == i ? FIRST_INSTANCE : SECOND_INSTANCE;`

```
0.973357599
1.82497641
```

Performance of `input1` became almost twice worse.

So my conclusion is as follows: uniformity of the array matter to JIT for some reason :)

---

Looking at it a bit further:

If we don't run `input` at all, and run `input2` 5 times instead of twice, we get this:

```
1.826676411
1.835746098
1.566231165
1.531194014
1.551068832
```

So it seems that JIT fully kicked in by the third loop. Note the times are ~1.5s.

Now, if we start off running `input1` twice, then proceed to `input2`:

```
input1: 2 times
0.507165973
0.509543633
input2: 5 times
1.270496255        <------ WAT?
1.817742481
1.804664757
1.845583904
1.846861045
```

It looks like JIT set up for `input1` actually helped `input2` a bunch, but then got thrown away and never quite recovered

Comment: But, how the JIT can make this difference between 2 inputs?

Comment: JIT watches the code execution, and when it sees a sequence that repeats and can be optimized, it does that. It doesn't care about the content of the array, it cares about the instructions order that JCM performs

Comment: Is that sure or just an opinion?? because I don't think that it can know that there is a sequence

Comment: It's an opinion, of course, I have no idea how JIT actually works internally

Comment: Yes I really want to know what is happening exactly there. I am reading about branch prediction like @Erwin Bolwidt said. Maybe I can find a reason